# Control PWM with potentiometer using atmega328p

Tags: avr, adc, pwm, atmega

I'm using an atmega328p and I want to control the PWM duty cycle with  a potentiometer.

The frequency is 20ms and the duty cycle is between 0 ms and 2 ms.
Problem : when I simulate this in Proteus the PWM did not work, this is my code:

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL // 16 MHz clock speed
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>


int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= 1<< PINB1 ;

    TCCR1A |= 1<< COM1A0 | 1<< COM1A1 | 1<<WGM11 ;
    TCCR1B |= 1<< WGM12 | 1<<WGM13 | 1<<CS10 | 1<<CS11 ;
    ICR1 = 4999 ; // 50 Hz

    ADCSRA |= 1<<ADEN | 1<< ADIE | 1<<ADPS2 | 1<<ADPS1 ;  // 64 prescaler
    ADMUX |= REFS0 ;
    sei();
    ADCSRA |= 1<<ADSC ;
    while (1) 
    {
    }
}

ISR(ADC_vect)
{
 uint8_t low = ADCL ;
 uint16_t tenvar = ADCH << 8 | low ;  // value from potentiometer 10 bit

 OCR1A = 4999 - ((499/1024)*tenvar ); // OCR1A is between 4999 and 4500 (4500 represent 2ms )


 ADCSRA |= 1<< ADSC ;
 }
```

Comment: In addition to the misunderstanding of integer math, try this without interrupts but by merely polling the ADC, and find a way to indicate the reading (serial port, etc).  Your project sounds enough like an **duino based "server tester" that you could probably learn a lot by studying a published project for one, or even temporarily test your hardware with such an approach before returning to a bare metal AVR approach.  You did connect the ADC supply voltage, right? (probably, as other basic things depend on it too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ((499/1024)*tenvar )
> ```

Oops.

```
(tenvar * 499L / 1024)
```

Unless you *really* don't care about the result always being 0.

Comment: What is the L and what is the difference between your code and mine

Comment: The `L` makes it a long (32-bit, to prevent overflow) constant, and `(499/1024)` is 0. Because integers.

Comment: aa ok got it ,  i tried your solution but still the same problem

Comment: I haven't actually checked all your register manipulations, I just found the most visible problem.

Comment: i tried the pwm without adc and it works fine but with adc it did not work

Answer (score 1):

i found the problem :
i forgot to put

```
1<<REFS0
```

in ADMUX registre

and for simplicity i could have used

```
OCR1A = 4999 - (ADC * 499L / 1024  ) ;
```

instead of

```
uint8_t low = ADCL ;
uint16_t tenvar = ADCH << 8 | low ;  

OCR1A = 4999 - (tenvar * 499L / 1024);
```